# Use Gnome 3 with only the keyboard

Tags: 11.10, gnome

Unity runs too slow in my machine, and Gnome-shell works very well. I don't like very much Gnome-shell but I'm doing my best effort. But one thing that I can't find is how to select a different windows or pick something from the left dock with the keyboard.

I mean, you hit the Win key, and the Activity panels shows. Then, the most obvious is that with the keyboard I can pick some window, with tab change from Windows to Applications, etc.

But NO, seems that I can press a key to show the Activities screen, but then I have the pick the mouse and click in the place that I want to go.

Recently I went to presentation about accessibility in a Google Developer Day, and the presenter says that if we forget everything that she says, we have just to remember "you have to unplug your mouse and be able to use your application".

Gnome 3 says hundred of times that is the "most accessible desktop", but how they can miss use the system with just the keyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to switch from the Windows screen to the Applications screen, but there are ways to launch applications and switch windows using the keyboard in gnome-shell.

#### Alt-Tab

Your question only mentions the Activites pane, but I'll mention this method for completeness, and because it most closely matches the behaviour of several other environments: To switch between applications, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. To switch between multiple windows of the same application, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. Note for non-US-keyborad users: To switch between multiple windows of the same application, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key above Tab</kbd>.

#### Searching in the Activities pane

The "type to search" field in the top right of the Activities pane is one of my favourite parts of gnome-shell. To launch an application without touching the mouse, press the "Win key" (here I'll call it <kbd>Super</kbd>) and type the first few letters of the application's name. A list of applications matching your text will appear. Use the up and down arrows to highlight the one you want, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For example, if I press <kbd>Super</kbd> and type "libr", the applications in the LibreOffice suite are listed for me, and I can select one.

The same method applies to switching windows: if you select an application that's already running, the shell will switch you to that application instead of opening a new instance of it. For example, if I already have Firefox open, and it press <kbd>Super</kbd> and type "firef" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get one of my existing Firefox windows instead of a new one.

So what if you want a new instance of an application that's already running? Select the application you want and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### The Window Navigator extension

This is an extension that allows you to select windows in the activities pane using keystrokes instead of mouse clicks.

[These instructions](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-11-10-using-ppa.html) explain how to enable a PPA with some gnome-shell extensions. The relevant commands are as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-windows-navigator
```

After installing, restart gnome-shell (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type "r" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>). If you use gnome-tweak-tool, you may need to launch it and enable the Window Navigator extension under Shell Extensions.

Once the extension is installed and enabled, you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> in the Activities pane to see a number hover over each window. Press a number key to switch to its corresponding window.

#### Update

There are plenty of other tips and explanations in the Gnome Project's [GnomeShell Cheat Sheet](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet).

Comment: I was looking something like that extension. I guess that we have to fill a lot of gaps in Gnome3 shell with extensions and tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Gnome Shell has ways to go before it's really accessible. I don't really understand what the question is, but I would like to recommend that you try Unity 2D if you like Unity but feel it's slow. Unity 2D is quite nice and has the features from Unity, but is much faster on some hardware.

Comment: The question is how to use the Gnome-shell's activity panel with the keyboard. Unity is usable with the keyboard as well, but It's too slow in my computer. Unity 2d is not an option for me, because still slow and disables the hardware acceleration (composition).

Comment: Hmm. That's strange. I would love to hear some details about your hardware if  Gnome Shell is fast while Unity 2D is slow.